# Postback triggers problem

Tags: asp.net, gridview, triggers, updatepanel, postback

I have a gridview in which I display file names getting from Database. I have made the file name as a link button in my gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gdvMainList" runat="server" CssClass="Grid" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="dtsFilesUploaded" 
AllowPaging="True" DataKeyNames="Id" SkinID="PagedGridView" AllowSorting="True" 
onrowediting="gdvMainList_RowEditing" OnRowDataBound="gdvMainList_RowDataBound"                                                     onrowupdating="gdvMainList_RowUpdating" onrowcommand="gdvMainList_RowCommand">                                                    
<Columns>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="File Name" SortExpression="FileName">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbFileName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FileName") %>' OnClick="OpenFile" CausesValidation="false"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Uploaded On" SortExpression="CreatedDateTime">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblCreatedDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CreatedDateTime") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="glCategoryId">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblglCategoryId" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GeneralLookup.LookupItem") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlglCategoryId" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry2" DataSourceID="dtsglCategoryId"                                                            DataTextField="LookupItem" DataValueField="Id" AppendDataBoundItems="true" Width="120px">
</asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedBy" HeaderText="Created By" Visible="false" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The link button has a method Onclick="OpenFile" and the code of Open file is:

```
protected void OpenFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
        string fileName = btn.Attributes["FileName"].ToString();

        //string path = Server.MapPath(".") + "\\Files\\" + fileName;
        string path = Server.MapPath("~") + "Upload\\" + this.fileUpload.FileName;
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + fileName);
            string type = "Application/word";
            if (type != "")
                Response.ContentType = type;
            Response.WriteFile(path);
            Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
        }   
    }
```

Now the problem is, this code does not work in update panel and works very fine without update panel. That's why I am trying to add these lines to make a post back.

```
<Triggers>
     <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnFileUploadSave" />
     <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lbFileName" />
```

Control Id btnFileUploadSave is another image button in my file that is being used to upload file. Because upload file was also not possible in update panel without this.

Anyway when I run this code, the following exception occurs:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

A control with ID 'lbFileName' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'upAttachFile'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: A control with ID 'btnOpenFile' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'upAttachFile'.

Please help if anyone can. I have wasted a lotttttttttttttt of my time on this.

Here is the GUI of my aspx page:

[image]

Comment: I think `URGENT` is not necessary here

Comment: Please note `Urgent` is considered rude here. People here are helping out for nothing and you have no right to make demands on their time or at what time they help you.

Comment: Where are your btnOpenFile & upAttachFile controls you mentioned?

Comment: @KoMet: Ohh sorry, it was "lbFileName", I have updated my post.And the upAttachFile is the Id of my UpdatePanel.

Comment: "!" isn't that great either, you remind of the species called "customer"

Comment: how can I accept an answer if it is not fulfilling my requirement? The upcoming readers will think that as answer otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another alternative for this. I open a new page using window.open() on clicking my link button. That solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't define a control in an ItemTemplate as an UpdatePanel trigger.

For a solution, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826654/invalidoperationexception-postback-trigger-cannot-find-a-control-within-the-item) out. Basically you have to register the control as trigger in the OnItemDataBound event.

Another solution for you is perhaps the [AsyncFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/asyncfileupload/asyncfileupload.aspx), which doesn't require a full postback to work.

**EDIT:** fixed first link.

Comment: I am registering the control but nothing happens !!

Comment: I used these lines to register my Link button : LinkButton lb = ((LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lbFileName"));
                lb.Attributes.Add("FileName", lb.Text);
                ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(lb);

Comment: Try RegisterPostBackControl instead of async

Comment: I tried both. When I use RegisterPostBack, it just post back the page. My file does not get open.